# EditText.setError(null) not working in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm having a little trouble with Xamarin's implementation of Android EditText.setError.

Most of the answers around here say that to dismiss an error message you just call setError(null), but Xamarin won't compile with it, claiming that no overload accepts only 1 argument. Unfortunately, giving it setError(null, null) is also not working because there are two overloads that use two arguments and it doesn't know which one to use (and will not compile).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the first `null` argument in `SetError` to either `string` or `Java.Lang.ICharSequence`:

```
EditText editText;
editText.SetError((string)null, null);
editText.SetError((Java.Lang.ICharSequence)null, null);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, any ideas as to why this works like that?

Comment: `null` can be resolved to either `string` or `Java.Lang.ICharSequence` so the symbol by itself is ambiguous, thus the compiler error. Typecasting `null` to either tells the compiler what method signature to use.